# laravel install bootstrap with composer not work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, composer-php

laravel install bootstrap with composer not work.

I use command

```
composer require twbs/bootstrap:4.0.0-alpha.6
```

after that. I see file composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.6.4",
        "laravel/framework": "5.4.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.6"
    },
```

It has a folder "twbs" in "vendor"

I try code bootstrap in welcome.blade.php but it did not work.

I do not know if I need any additional config?

Comment: Can you show how you're trying to included it in your `welcome.blade.php`?

Comment: include href="{{asset("vendor\twbs\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css")}}"  ?

Comment: `asset()` will just point the public directory of your site (unless you've changed the default set up). Are you gulp/mix for any of your assets? If not and you don't want to you could just symlink.